# Is there a way to DRY using SimpleSchema and Typescript?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, typescript, dry

You can use Typescript interfaces as elementary schema for your database, but using SimpleSchema and Collection2 gives a real control over your database schema.

Is there a way to better integrate a Typescript **interface** with **SimpleSchema** (in order to stick with the DRY principle)?

Check the duplicity between the *Demo interface* and *schema* in this sample code:

### demo.collection.ts

```js
import { MongoObservable } from "meteor-rxjs";
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

export interface Demo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  location?: string;
  owner?: string;
}

const schema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: String,
  age: SimpleSchema.Integer,
  location: { type: String, optional: true},
  owner:  { type: String, optional: true}
});

let demoCollection = new Mongo.Collection<Demo>('demo-collection');
let demoObservable = new MongoObservable.Collection<Demo>(demoCollection);

demoCollection.attachSchema(schema);

export const DemoCollection = demoObservable;
```

### demo-data.services.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableCursor } from "meteor-rxjs";

import { Demo, DemoCollection } from "../../../../both/collections/demo.collection";

@Injectable()
export class DemoDataService {
  private data: ObservableCursor<Demo>;

  constructor() {
    this.data = DemoCollection.find({});
  }

  public getData(): ObservableCursor<Demo> {
    return this.data;
  }

  public insertData(value: Demo): any {
    return DemoCollection.insert(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: is [this](https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs/blob/master/definitions/simple-schema.d.ts) what you're looking for?

Comment: perhaps [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/610#issuecomment-229091439) will help, too.

Comment: @EliranMalka, these are for Typings definitions. What I want to avoid is to type similar information twice. I have to inform that, for example, name is a 'string' for the interface definition and again define it as a 'String' for the schema object. But it seems the only way would be creating something like a meta-programming to generate these vars.